# How to create bookmark in Komodo Edit 8.5 for FTP folder?

Tags: ftp, bookmarks, komodo, komodoedit

I used to use Coda and there was a function which allowing me to create bookmarks for ftp folders.
Is there any analog function in Komodo Edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the following plugin to emulate this functionality:

- [Sites](http://community.activestate.com/node/6894)

Restart Komodo Edit, then right click a folder and left click the Favorite option.